# How to create jasper report by giving output of one query as input of another

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I tried using dataset. But how can I give one dataset queries output as input to another dataset.

For example, balancesheet type report view.

My first query is

```sql
SELECT column_name_one FROM table WHERE C_GL_PRIMARY='LIABILITY'
```

Suppose this query returns me 2 rows, like DEPOSIT,LOAN.
My second query is

```sql
SELECT colum_name_second FROM table WHERE C_GL_ONE='column_name_one'
```

(i did it using datagrid and is working)

### for example

```
DEPOSIT
       term deposit
       pigmy deposit
LOANS
       term loan
        pigmy loan
```

---

Till here everything is fine but now i have one more query which need output of second query as input for this query.

```sql
select column_name_third from table where C_GL_TWO='colum_name_second'
```

Here i am not able to put "colum_name_second" as input becoz it this fiels is under list not in details..

My report should look like this

---

```
DEPOSIT
       term deposit
                 new term deposit
                 old term deposit
       pigmy deposit
                 ww pigmy deposit
                 bbb deposit
LOANS
       term loan
                new tem loan
                current term loan
        pigmy loan
                pigmyloannew
```

Can anybody help me ...Is there any way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1ST-Create the Parameter in Main report query and enter the parameter value in HashMap to populate it.
2nd-Create the parameter in dataset and use the parameter in dataset query.$p{Dataset_parameter}
3rd-If you are using List component right click on then go Edit list data source then click parameter then add the parameter of dataset and configure it with Main query output attribute.

```
Ex-select ID,NAME from CALENDAR WHERE REGION=$P{REGION_ID}--REGION_ID main report parameter
   SELECT HOLIDAY_NAME,DATE_PICKER FROM HOLIDAYS WHERE CAL_ID=$P{CAL_ID} --CAL_ID dataset  
parameter.configure as per instruction above with $P{CAL_ID} with expression $F{ID}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description this should just be a single query:

```sql
SELECT t1.column_name_one, t2.column_name_two, t3.column_name_three 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on (t2.C_GL_ONE = t1.column_name_one)
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on (t3.C_GL_TWO = t2.column_name_two)
WHERE t1.C_GL_PRIMARY='LIABILITY'
```

Then the report would be grouped to show the data exactly as in your desired report output.

Comment: If you are letting the end user set these parameters at runtime, then you would want to expose these parameters as input controls. But in your case it sounds like you're not doing that.